# Display jQuery validation message on different element

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, unobtrusive-validation

```
<div class="editor-field">
    @Html.TextBox("manager-control", "", new { id = "manager-control", @class = "form-control", placeholder = "Type to search..." })
    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.manager, new { id = "manager-dn" })
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.manager)
</div>
```

`manager-control` is an autocomplete, autocomplete select handler adds a value to the hidden field which represents the value for the manager. I can enable the validation message for the hidden field, that's fine, but the validation message itself is displayed outside the form.

I'd like to display the message itself on the `manager-control` element. What would be the best way to do that? The `manager-dn` field MUST have a value when the form is submitted, so simply saying that the `manager-control` should be filled out will not work.

The two ways I can think of are to use LabelFor instead of HiddenFor, and thus display an ugly text string, or find a way to display the validation message above the input.

EDIT:

This is useful in situations where you don't want to display the value of the selected AutoComplete item to the user but do want to validate that something has been selected.

Comment: Constructive feedback for downvote please, don't just driveby.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I've found, there's no way to actually change which element the validation message displays next to.

My solution:

```
<div class="editor-field">
    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.manager, new { id = "manager-dn", @class="form-control", style="position:absolute;z-index:-1;" })
    @Html.TextBox("manager-control", "", new { id = "manager-control", @class = "form-control", placeholder = "Type to search..." })                        
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.manager)
</div>
```

This hides the TextBoxFor behind the AutoComplete textbox. It retains the `form-control` class as without it, there are some CSS attributes that are missed out and the validation message will not display in the same place.

That being said, changing the `z-index` will also mean it no longer automatically fills to the size of its container. This can be fixed by using jQuery or JavaScript to programmatically set the width to that of the element it's hidden behind, in this case;

```
$('#manager-dn').width($('#manager-control').width());
```